# Decision Trees Python Classes in Terminal Nodes

Tags: python, decision-tree

I implement decision trees with python. I do cross-validation with grid-search to identify the optimal model parameters of the tree.

```
dtc = DecisionTreeClassifier()

parameter_grid = {'splitter': ['best', 'random'], 
        'min_samples_split': [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
        'min_samples_leaf': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
        'criterion': ['gini', 'entropy'],
        'random_state': [0],
        'max_depth':[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
        }


    cross_validation = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=10)
    grid_search = GridSearchCV(dtc, param_grid=parameter_grid, cv=cross_validation)
    grid_search.fit(x, y)

dtree = grid_search.best_estimator_

    dtree.fit(x,y)
```

The figure shows the resulting tree with the grid_search.best_params_ combination getting the best grid_search.best_score_.

[image]

I don't understand why the right terminal node in the left branch of the tree still has values = [97, 148]. I don't get why other combinations of model parameters, which would again split this terminal node, get no better accuracy during cross-validation and grid-search. I dont really have an explanation for this terminal node, not pure at all. Can somebody explain why a tree with such a terminal node gets a better accuracy than a tree with further splits?